# Building dojo generate multiple files

Tags: build, dojo

I'm using the building tool of dojo to generate a single file dojo.js, but I don't know why I'm getting  multiple files.

This is my example profile:

```
var profile = (function(){
    return {
        basePath: "../../../",
        releaseDir: "./app",
        releaseName: "lib",
        action: "release",
        layerOptimize: "closure",
        optimize: "closure",
        mini: true,
        stripConsole: "warn",
        selectorEngine: "lite",

        defaultConfig: {
            hasCache:{
                "dojo-built": 1,
                "dojo-loader": 1,
                "dom": 1,
                "host-browser": 1,
                "config-selectorEngine": "lite"
            },
            async: 1
        },
 
        staticHasFeatures: {
            'dojo-trace-api': 0,
            'dojo-log-api': 0,
            'dojo-publish-privates': 0,
            'dojo-sync-loader': 0,
            'dojo-test-sniff': 0
        },
 
        packages:['dojo'],
 
        layers: {
            "dojo/dojo": {
                include: ["dojo/domReady"],
                customBase: true,
                boot: true
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

This is my .bat:

```
./util/buildscripts/build profile=cgl-dojo
```

After execute it, this is the release folder:

```
app
\---lib
    \---dojo
        +---cldr
        |   \---nls
        |       +---ar
        |       +---ca
        |       +---cs
        |       +---da
        |       +---de
        |       +---el
        |       +---en
        |       +---en-au
        |       +---en-ca
        |       +---en-gb
        |       +---es
        |       +---fi
        |       +---fr
        |       +---fr-ch
        |       +---he
        |       +---hu
        |       +---it
        |       +---ja
        |       +---ko
        |       +---nb
        |       +---nl
        |       +---pl
        |       +---pt
        |       +---pt-pt
        |       +---ro
        |       +---ru
        |       +---sk
        |       +---sl
        |       +---sv
        |       +---th
        |       +---tr
        |       +---zh
        |       +---zh-hant
        |       +---zh-hk
        |       \---zh-tw
        +---data
        |   +---api
        |   \---util
        +---date
        +---dnd
        +---errors
        +---fx
        +---io
        +---nls
        |   +---ar
        |   +---az
        |   +---bg
        |   +---ca
        |   +---cs
        |   +---da
        |   +---de
        |   +---el
        |   +---es
        |   +---fi
        |   +---fr
        |   +---he
        |   +---hr
        |   +---hu
        |   +---it
        |   +---ja
        |   +---kk
        |   +---ko
        |   +---nb
        |   +---nl
        |   +---pl
        |   +---pt
        |   +---pt-pt
        |   +---ro
        |   +---ru
        |   +---sk
        |   +---sl
        |   +---sv
        |   +---th
        |   +---tr
        |   +---uk
        |   +---zh
        |   \---zh-tw
        +---promise
        +---request
        +---resources
        |   \---images
        +---router
        +---rpc
        +---selector
        +---store
        |   +---api
        |   \---util
        +---_base
        \---_firebug
```

I need a release folder with only one file, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The entire tree of registered packages is always built because the build tool has no way of knowing whether or not you are conditionally requiring other modules within your application. There is no way to make the build system only output one file, and in fact a single file is a bad idea because each locale has its own set of localisation rules. If you want to reduce the number of files after a build, you can just delete all the ones you don’t want.